# Bootstrap 3 form validator interfering with click event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm working on a project for a client and they're using Bootstrap 3's form validation widget. And there's one submit button that I'm trying to place a custom '.click()' event on but it isn't being called no matter what.

In inspect element I can see there are many click event handlers from bootstrap.min.js. I'm thinking this is the culprit. Does anyone have experience with this problem in the past?

Code:

```
var fieldsFilled = false;

   //Iterate through all the input fields/textarea of the feedback form
   $('#fbForm').find('input, textarea').each(function () {
       //Each time a key is pressed while the input has focus
       $(this).keyup(function () {
           //Check if fields are empty
           fieldsFilled = checkFormFieldsEmpty('#fbForm') && $('#terms').is(":checked");

           //If fields are filled and terms is checked then enable Submit
           if(fieldsFilled) {
               $("#btnSubmit").css("pointer-events","auto");
           } else {
               $("#btnSubmit").css("pointer-events","none");
           }
       });
   });

   $('#terms').change(function () {
       fieldsFilled = checkFormFieldsEmpty('#fbForm') && $('#terms').is(":checked");

       if(fieldsFilled) {
           $("#btnSubmit").css("pointer-events","auto");
        } else {
           $("#btnSubmit").css("pointer-events","none"); 
       }
   });

   //Checks if the form id has blank text fields
   function checkFormFieldsEmpty(id) {
       var filled = true;

       $(id).find('input, textarea').each(function () {
           //Check whether the input/textarea is blank
           if(!$(this).val()) {
               //If the input/textarea is empty return false
               filled = false;
           }
       });

       return filled;
   }

    $(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (event) {
        alert('this');

        if($('#btnSubmit').hasClass('disabled')) {
            alert('empty');
        } else {
            grecaptcha.execute();
            grecaptcha.render();
        }
    });
```

other part:

```
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <div  class="text-center">
        <h2><b>Feedback Form</b></h2><br>
    </div>
    <!-- Name: Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name "class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of First Name must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $name ;?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Surname: Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="surname">Last Name</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="surname" id="surname" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of Last Name must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $surname ;?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>



    <!-- Country: Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="country">Country</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Country"name="country" id="country" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of Country must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $country ;?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>



    <!-- Email: Email input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>  
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail Address" value="<?= $email ;?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Comment -->

     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class=" input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Please enter comment..." rows="5" cols="25" data-minlength="10" data-error="Minimum Lenght of Comment must be made up of at least 10 characters!" value="<?= $comment ;?>" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- GDPR Disclaimer -->
    <div class="form-group text-justify">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="comment">GDPR Disclaimer</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <p>By ticking the below tick box, I hereby give my consent for the personal information which I am providing in this application to be processed and recorded by the Agriculture Directorate, and to exchange this information with Public Authorities, Government Departments and any other third parties, as necessary , in order to process this application and as permitted by Maltese Law.</p>
    </div>
    </div>


    <!-- GDPR Checkbox -->


      <div class="form-group text-center">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>

        <input  type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Please check the GDPR Disclaimercheck box in order to be able to submit the data" required>
        I agree
      </label>

      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>



    <!-- reCaptcha -->
<!--  

    <div class="form-group text-center">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="g-recaptcha col-md-4" data-callback="verifyRecaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="expiredRecaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="6Lf3JDAUAAAAAJ3Y4oPhVeuAx0K98sCCYju7HcT1" ></div><!-- change this if moved to website and register website at google recaptcha
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" data-recaptcha="true" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
-->    
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4"><br>
       <!-- NOTE: Made some changes for click events as advised here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute -->
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfDBGcUAAAAABnYRk1ZQkapzCs8c1Rr2ZARMchF" data-callback="onSubmit" data-size="invisible"></div>
        <!-- Test: 6LfuAWcUAAAAAEKjLeOZfygAMxAeld1k4UUMGnfN -->
        <!-- Live: 6LfDBGcUAAAAABnYRk1ZQkapzCs8c1Rr2ZARMchF -->
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a `type="submit"` button inside a form tag. Its normal behavior is to submit the form where the consequence is to reload the page (or load the URL found in the `action` attribute of the opening form tag). That is instantaneous. It doesn't "wait" for the execution of anything else on the actual page.

If you want to perform tasks prior to submit, you have to [prevent that normal behavior](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // ... Your additionnal validations

    // When ready to submit:
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

And, by the way, this condition `if($('#btnSubmit').hasClass('disabled'))` will never be true... Since the click event won't fire on a disabled element.